# Regex pattern to match the string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

What is the regex pattern to match a string starting with abc-def-xyz and ending with anything ??

Comment: What happens when you try it? `samplemethod(filter=r'abc-def')`

Comment: I guess its not taking that pattern, because i am not getting any output for it

Comment: Perhaps the pattern does not match anything in the target string? What is the implementation of the function? Can you post it here?

Comment: So what will be the regex expression for abc-def

Comment: Literally the pattern is `abc-def`. Provide more details about the data on which you are trying to match.

Comment: I am trying to fetch the list of hosts for eg: (abc-def.somevalue.desktop.rul.com) and somevalue ranges from 1 to 100. So say 100 hosts in total. But somehow its giving me other hosts as well along them which i dont want hence, wanna restrict it to by providing the pattern abc-def

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Since you only want to match host names that begin with `abc-def` you can simply use `str.startswith()`:

```
hosts = ['abc-def.1.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.2.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.3.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.4.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.44.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.100.desktop.rul.com',
         'qwe-rty.100.desktop.rul.com',
         'z.100.desktop.rul.com',
         '192.168.1.10',
         'abc-def.100abc.desktop.rul.com']
filtered_hosts = [host for host in hosts if host.startswith('abc-def')]
print filtered_hosts
```

**Output**

```
['abc-def.1.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.2.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.3.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.4.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.44.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.100.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.100abc.desktop.rul.com']
```

Original regex solution follows.

---

Let's say that your data is a list of host names such as these:

```
hosts = ['abc-def.1.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.2.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.3.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.4.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.44.desktop.rul.com',
         'abc-def.100.desktop.rul.com',
         'qwe-rty.100.desktop.rul.com',
         'z.100.desktop.rul.com',
         '192.168.1.10',
         'abc-def.100abc.desktop.rul.com']

import re

pattern = re.compile(r'abc-def\.\d+\.')
filtered_hosts = [host for host in hosts if pattern.match(host)]
print filtered_hosts
```

**Output**

```
['abc-def.1.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.2.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.3.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.4.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.44.desktop.rul.com', 'abc-def.100.desktop.rul.com']
```

The regex pattern says to match any lines that start with `abc-def.` followed by one or more digits, followed by a dot.

If you wanted to match a more generic pattern such as any sequence of 3 lowercase letters followed by a `-` and then another 3 lowercase letters, you could do this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[a-z]{3}-[a-z]{3}\.\d+\.')
```

Now the output also includes `'qwe-rty.100.desktop.rul.com'`.

Comment: Thanx. But the regex what you have provided..can you just limit it to abc-def and repost. Because the list also contains hosts such as abc-def.somevalue.desktop.rul.com, abc-def.somevalue1-somevalue2.desktop.rul.com, abc-def.somevalue-somevalue1-somevalue2.desktop.rul.com

Comment: Basically i just want a regex pattern that fetches the host name starting with abc-def thats it

Comment: Sorry about that. There is adequate explanation of the pattern for you to be able to change it for yourself. It's quite obvious.

Comment: And you don't need a regex for this. Just use `str.startswith()`.